# how to use toolbar to connect two view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

have two view controller(FirstViewController,sixViewController),i create a toolbar button in the navigation bar using interface builder,when i press the toolbar button it should direct me to sixViewcontroller,in the sixViewcontroller i have back button to return firstviewController with slide in animation,my toolbar name is Item.help need guys coz I'm still new for iOS.

```
UIViewController *viewController6 = [[sixViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController5 = [[FifthViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FifthViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: what u have tried? Have u used pushViewController and popViewController?

Comment: i try connect by calling the button using ibaction of the button to call but i dono how to to implement it

Comment: so u want to know code to write in button touch up inside event?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you would be much better off using a NavigationController which handles placing the navigation bar and managing the viewController stack automatically.

The UINavigationController class reference is a good place to start

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html